# Type of "foreach" in Scala

Tags: scala, types

I have example code:

```
  def test = {
    val l : Seq[(String, String)] = Seq()
    val foo : (String, String) => Unit = {case (a, b)=>}
    l.foreach[Unit](foo)
  }
```

It gives me the next error:

```
Error:(8, 21) type mismatch;
 found   : (String, String) => Unit
 required: ((String, String)) => Unit
    l.foreach[Unit](foo)
```

As far as I understand `foreach` has a type `(A=>U)=>Unit` where:

- `A` is template parameter of my collection and
- `U` is template parameter of `foreach` itself

My question is why is `((String, String)) => Unit` required? Where do the extra brackets come from?

Comment: You transform `foo` into `((String, String)) => Unit` using `tupled` : `l.foreach(foo.tupled)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check in the REPL, you'll see that `foo` is a `<function2>`, that is, a function that takes 2 argument:

```
scala> val foo : (String, String) => Unit = {case (a, b)=>}
foo: (String, String) => Unit = <function2>
```

`.foreach` however expects a function that takes a single arguement (of type `A`), which in your case is a `Tuple2`.
If you set `foo` to be a `<function1>`, then it works:

```
scala> val foo : ((String, String)) => Unit = {case (a, b)=>}
foo: ((String, String)) => Unit = <function1>

scala> val l : Seq[(String, String)] = Seq()
l: Seq[(String, String)] = List()

scala> l.foreach[Unit](foo)

scala>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from top.

You have

```
val l: Seq[(String, String)]
```

that is a `Seq` of tuples of two strings. So each of the elements of `l` is of type `(String, String)` which is a syntactic sugar for `Tuple2[String, String]`.

Now you have

```
val foo: (String, String) => Unit
```

that is a function of **two** arguments each being `String`. Again, the type signature above is syntactic sugar for `Function2[String, String, Unit]`.

Considering the above your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
def test = {
    val l: Seq[Tuple2[String, String]] = Seq()
    val foo: Function2[String, String, Unit] = {case (a, b)=>}
    l.foreach[Unit](foo)
}
```

`foreach` expects a single argument function, i.e. a `Function1[T, R]`, thus the type mismatch.

Comment: Thank you. It is my Haskell experience play a joke with me. Forgot that brackets in `val foo: (String, String) => Unit` is not part of a type, but part of function declaration syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The type definition `foo: (String, String) => Unit` says that `foo` is a function which takes two parameters of type `String`. However, your sequence `l: Seq[(String, String)]` contains tuples of type `type t = (String, String)`. Thus, calling `l.foreach` expects a function which is applicable to the tuple type `t`. Thus, it expects a function of type `t => Unit`, which is equivalent to `((String, String)) => Unit`.